# Unity LoadImageIntoTexture memory leak

Tags: c#, web, memory-leaks, unity-game-engine

I am building something that requires users to load images from an external folder, display them and sort them into different folders individually.

My problem is that each time I load in a new image the memory usage goes up but never comes back down. This happens when i run it as an .exe or in editor. When I run it in editor the memory usage doesn't go down even when I stop running it, I have to manually exit the unity editor and restart it. If I go back to an image I've seen the memory doesn't increase, so I know that it's keeping these images in memory and I don't know how to remove them.

I have checked all the resources I can find about this online and have followed and changed as much as I can but my problem is still happening. Any help would be great.

I added the code that loads and sets the texture as the main texture below. the memory leak does not happen when I comment out the LoadImageIntoTexture line.

```
IEnumerator LoadImage(string userFolder)
        {
            WWW newFile = new WWW("file://"+ userFolder + pictures[current]);
            yield return newFile;
            Destroy(editTex);
            editTex = new Texture2D(1920, 1080, TextureFormat.DXT1, false);
            newFile.LoadImageIntoTexture(editTex);
            newFile.Dispose();
            newFile = null;
            Resources.UnloadUnusedAssets();
            System.GC.Collect();
        }
```

Comment: Did you figure it out yet?  If not you might want to check out this blog: https://software.intel.com/en-us/blogs/2015/02/05/unity-tips-1

Comment: Sorry - I wanted to include the following in the above comment: Working with Textures                                                                                                        
Don't create Mipmaps for textures unless really needed
Use compressed textures
Don't set textures to readable (CPU R/W) except when needed. This avoids extra CPU copies, markers, etc.
Reduce the size of textures depending on screen resolution
Android & Small Screens:
On models - skip the top MIP (Quality Settings>Rendering>Texture Quality) 
Separate RGB (compressable) from Alpha (non compressable) channels